# Make struct not in header accessible by other files

Tags: c, struct

In the C language, suppose I define `struct s`, inside a file `f.c`. I don't want this `struct` to be accessible by other people so I don't put it in `f.h`. In my project, I have many other files including `g.c` that wants to access the `struct s` in `f.c`.

Is there a way to make this possible? I am thinking that `s` would have to be a global `extern` variable declared in `g.h`. They would link during compilation. I am not sure if this is possible or the correct/best way to go about doing something like this.

Comment: A type's definition must be available prior to its use. You either use a header, or you copy paste the definition of the struct. There is no way to share types between translation units.

Comment: You'll have to create APIs in `f.c` that create and modify this structure. You pass a `void *` back to caller so it can't access its fields.

Comment: Define *accessible by other people*.

Answer (score 4):

You can add to your header file a forward declaration to the type and it can be treated as an opaque (incomplete) type.

```
struct s;
```

Other people can now refer to `struct s *`, but they cannot use a `struct s`, since the type is incomplete to them.

If you provide APIs, they can call the APIs to create, modify, and destroy instances of `struct s`.

```
enum struct_s_field {
    S_FIELD_NAME,
    S_FIELD_VALUE,
    /* ... */
};

struct s * make_s ();
void unmake_s(struct s *);
void update_s(struct s *, enum struct_s_field, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create APIs in `f.c` that initialize, read, and write `struct s` structures. To hide the contents of this structure from the caller, you return a `void *` back to the caller that it uses in subsequent calls to `f.c` APIs.

For example:

```
void *pS;

pS = sInit();

void *sInit(void)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(struct s));
}
```

Comment: @d3l `void*` are a hole in the type system. Any object pointer in C converts to and from `void*` implicitly without the need for casts of any sort. Why make such a hole when you can use pointers to declared but not defined structs as in @jxh's answer?

Comment: Why return `void *` when it could return `struct s*` and avoid the cast?

Comment: @PSkocik Good explanation. I'll leave this here for future reference.